# How to get an error when creating an array with duplicate keys?

Tags: php, arrays, hashmap, syntax-error

reader,

I recently lost 40 minutes in debugging because a coworker did a little mistake duplicating rows and PHP didn't triggered any error.

Original lines were similar to

```
$files = [
    'identifier1' => '/path/to/file1'
];
```

Intended lines after duplication

```
$files = [
    'identifier1' => '/path/to/file1',
    'identifier2' => '/path/to/file2',
    'identifier3' => '/path/to/file3'
];
```

How the lines really were

```
$files = [
    'identifier1' => '/path/to/file1',
    'identifier1' => '/path/to/file2',
    'identifier1' => '/path/to/file3'
];
```

Which is the same as

```
$files = [
    'identifier1' => '/path/to/file3'
];
```

Is there a way to make php trigger an error (even if it's only a warning) when you mistakenly try to define an array with duplicate keys?

We would like to enable that option globally, and error_reporting(E_ALL) don't work sadly.

Comment: same key will automatically over-write. So you will never get same key two times in array at-least. so basically `$files = [
    'identifier1' => '/path/to/file1',
    'identifier2' => '/path/to/file2',
    'identifier3' => '/path/to/file3'
];` not possible to achieve in php. Now what is your question after this?

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones  he showed same keys, so they were over-written. He is not talking about values.

Comment: @AlivetoDie You're right. I was going to suggest to also include http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php to check the keys, but it turns out that doesn't work anyway because `count($files)` returns 1 anyway and not 3.

Answer (score 0):

This is not considered an error in PHP. It is simply overwriting a key/value pair.

The only way to check this is to check the `count()` of `$files` after you define it to verify it has however many items you think it should. You can then throw an `Exception` or log an error if the count is too low.

Answer (score 0):

If you provide your source as a pre-built array:

```
$list = [
    'one' => 1,
    'two' => 2,
    'one' => 3,
];
```

Then it is simply not possible to detect duplicate keys with a run-time check, as this code is compiled as if it were:

```
$list = [
    'two' => 2,
    'one' => 3,
];
```

I.e., the duplicate key essentially disappears before your code runs and any code you write will simply never see the first entry. If you write your code as individual lines:

```
$list['one'] = 1;
$list['two'] = 2;
$list['one'] = 3;
```

Then you have a few options. You could create a class that implements `ArrayAccess`, then write the `offsetSet()` method to check to see if the given offset already exists whenever a new offset is written. The class would essentially be usable wherever an array is.

```
class UniqueArray implements ArrayAccess
{

    protected $data = [];

    public function offsetExists($key)
    {
        return array_key_exists($key, $this->data);
    }

    public function offsetGet($key)
    {
        return $this->data[$key];
    }

    public function offsetSet($key, $value)
    {
        if ($this->offsetExists($key)) {
            throw new Exception("key '$key' already exists");
        }
        $this->data[$key] = $value;
    }

    public function offsetUnset($key)
    {
        unset($this->data[$key]);
    }

}

$list = new UniqueArray();
$list['one'] = 1;
$list['one'] = 2; // throws an exception
```

I imagine that's probably more trouble than it's worth though.

Your only real option is static code analysis. You might write your own sniff for [PHPCS](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer) that attempts to find these duplicate key instances in the actual source code. Note this will require running the analysis tool on the source code to detect the issues.